Can I identify all connected Google Sheets (explore with sheets) created by a user using BigQuery?
One of our users has left the company, and I need to identify all connected Google Sheets they created before I deactivate their account. I also need to transfer ownership of these Sheets to another user.
I attempted to use Google Logs Explorer to find the information, but it didn't yield any results. I also ran a query, which provided me with a list of tables used by the user to create connected Google Sheets.
SELECT job_id, lbl.key,lbl.value,creation_time
FROM `region-australia-southeast1`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS, unnest(labels) as lbl
WHERE job_id like 'sheets_dataconnector_%'
order by creation_time desc --2023-07-12 10:22:26.558000 UTC


Hi Ankit , there is no direct  process   but for better solution if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.

Isn't it much easier to simply reset their password, log in as them and then do that?
Big query is a data warehouse, I don't think it has this type of Google admin connectivity out of the box. Although you might be able to achieve it by reading documentation and exploring Google apps scripts.
